# How to link only the user name to profile.php in moodle

Tags: php, html, moodle

I'm using php code in my moodle `frontpage.php`.

```
<?php echo get_string('usergreeting', 'theme_ui_1', $USER->firstname .' '. $USER->lastname); ?>
```

I want to link only user name with `profile.php` page, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$url = new moodle_url('/user/profile.php', array('id'=>$USER->id);
$link = html_writer::link($url, $USER->firstname .' '. $USER->lastname);
echo get_string('usergreeting', 'theme_ui_1', $link);
```

Comment: Thank you Russell England for reply. new code should be <?php $url = new moodle_url('/user/profile.php', array('id' => $USER->id)); ?>
                            <?php $link = html_writer::link($url, $USER->firstname .' '. $USER->lastname); ?> now it's working perfectly. Thank you again... 
                            <?php echo get_string('usergreeting', 'theme_ui_1', $link); ?>